# c++ returning dereference of a pointer causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a map pointer `m`, which is not a local variable of the function `getMap`, `getMap` returns a dereference of pointer `m`, and when I run the code below, I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, why returning dereference of a pointer causes Segmentation fault.

```
std::map<int, std::string> *m;

const std::map<int, std::string>& getMap(){
  m->insert(std::make_pair<int, std::string>(0, "hi"));
  return *m;
}

int main(){
  const std::map<int, std::string>& m = getMap();
  std::cout << "length: " << m.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably got segmentation fault as soon as you called `m->insert(…);` but such errors may get reported with a delay (unless you are debugging step by step).

Answer (score 3):

`m` is an uninitialized global pointer. The compiler gives it a default value of `nullptr`. So you just invoke undefined behaviour when you dereference it - it is likely that you try to read or write memory at a zero address which causes the segmentation fault.

How to fix:

- define a std::map object and make `m` point there

  ```
  std::map<int, std::string> glob_map;
  std::map<int, std::string> *m = &glob_map;
  ... remaining of code unchanged
  ```
- make `GetMap` return a temporary

  ```
  const std::map<int, std::string> getMap(){
    std::map<int, std::string> localmap
    localmap.insert(std::make_pair<int, std::string>(0, "hi"));
    return m;
  }

  int main(){
    const std::map<int, std::string>& m = getMap();
    std::cout << "length: " << m.size() << std::endl;
  }
  ```

That is a rather advanced method, since you use the fact that the lifetime of a temporary is extended when it is directly affected to a reference. The normal way would be to copy the temporary to a plain object (and let the optimizing compiler elide the unnecessary copy):

```
      const std::map<int, std::string> m = getMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize `m` at all and dereference on it is UB. You need to `new` (and `delete`) it.

If you don't have to use raw pointer, then don't use.

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;

const std::map<int, std::string>& getMap(){
  m.insert(std::make_pair<int, std::string>(0, "hi"));
  return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create and allocate a single pointer to a `std::map`, but not the `map` itself. Hence `m` points to nowhere, and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

You probably want something like

```
 std::map<int, std::string> *m = new map<int, std::string>();
```

Comment: Or maybe simply `std::map<int, std::string> m;`?

Comment: Please do not advice to use `new` for globals except in specific cases. Here it is enough to define a global map object and optionaly a pointer to it - do you intend to free it

Comment: @Melebius well, I was presuming OP was needing a pointer and an allocated object. But yes, that would work, too.

Comment: @SergeBallesta couldn't agree more!

Answer (score -1):

There's not problem with the code you've shown (other than that you never initialize m).

Probably the issue is somewhere else in the code.

The most likely issues are:

- You call `getMap` before m is initialized.
- You call `getMap` after m has been destroyed.

Use something like valgrind to identify which one it is and get more information about the problem.

Comment: There is an issue. `m` doesn't point to an object. You *must not* dereference something like that. It is clearly a bug.